# Spark dataframe filter a timestamp by just the date part

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How can I filter a spark dataframe that has a column of type timestamp but filter out by just the date part. I tried below, but it only matches if time is 00:00:00.

Basically I want the filter to match all rows with date `2020-01-01` (3 rows)

```
import java.sql.Timestamp

val df = Seq(
  (1, Timestamp.valueOf("2020-01-01 23:00:01")),
  (2, Timestamp.valueOf("2020-01-01 00:00:00")),
  (3, Timestamp.valueOf("2020-01-01 12:54:00")),
  (4, Timestamp.valueOf("2019-12-15 09:54:00")),
  (5, Timestamp.valueOf("2019-12-09 10:12:43"))
).toDF("someCol","someTimeStamp")

df.filter(df("someTimeStamp") === "2020-01-01").show

+-------+-------------------+
|someCol|      someTimeStamp|
+-------+-------------------+
|      2|2020-01-01 00:00:00|   // ONLY MATCHED with time 00:00
+-------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `to_date` function to extract the date from the timestamp:

```
scala> df.filter(to_date(df("someTimeStamp")) === "2020-01-01").show
+-------+-------------------+
|someCol|      someTimeStamp|
+-------+-------------------+
|      1|2020-01-01 23:00:01|
|      2|2020-01-01 00:00:00|
|      3|2020-01-01 12:54:00|
+-------+-------------------+
```